# Constructing an object from an array of color gradients

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of gradients that I am trying to pass to a charting library each time a function is called.

The library requires the gradient to be passed in as an object in this format:

```
[0, 'rgba(73,115,214,.15)'],
[1, 'rgba(73,115,214,.07)']
```

I have built an array of gradients like so:

```
var gradients = [
  [
    ['rgba(73,115,214,.15)'],
    ['rgba(148,196,168,.1)']        
  ],
  [
    ['rgba(73,115,214,.07)'],
    ['rgba(41,189,102,.12)']
  ]
]
```

Each time a function is called, I store an index value, and need to retrieve the corresponding gradient in the array. How do I retrieve a specific index value from `gradients` and construct it into the necessary format?

```
var index = -1;
function setData() {
   index = index + 1;

   //I Need a gradient!
}
```

For instance, if the index was 2, I would want to return:

```
[0, 'rgba(73,115,214,.07)'],
[1, 'rgba(41,189,102,.12)']
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, suppose your index is 3, do you expect [3, 'rgba(73,115,214,.07)'] to be returned ?

Comment: @JyotiPuri see edit to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle for code: http://jsfiddle.net/qp6kL5ms/1/

You can write your loop like this:

```
function setData() {
   index = index + 1;
   var resultantGradient = [];
   gradients[index].forEach(function(gradient, index) {
      resultantGradient.push([index, gradient]);
   });
   return resultantGradient;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out, the lib needs this to return resultantGradient inside brackets like so: [0,rgba(73,115,214,.15),1,rgba(148,196,168,.1)]. Am I able to place resultantGradient within the brackets or do I need to construct this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?
If you are preparing an hard coded data, do this.

```
var gradients = {
   "0" : "['rgba(73,115,214,.15)']",
   "1" : "['rgba(148,196,168,.1)']",
   "2" : "['rgba(73,115,214,.07)']",
   "3" : "['rgba(41,189,102,.12)']"
}
```

and while passing it you can prepare it by:

```
var globalArray = [];
for( var grad in gradients ) {
  var obj = [];
  var val = grad+","+gradients[grad];
  obj.push(val);
  globalArray.push(obj);
}
```

Now for your index thing which you mentioned, you can modify the function like this.

```
var globalArray = [];
// in your case you have show index as 2
function setData( index ){
   for( var grad in gradients ) {
       if ( grad < index ) {
         var obj = [];
         var val = grad+","+gradients[grad];
         obj.push(val);
         globalArray.push(obj);
       }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expected?

```
var index = -1;
function setData() {
    var result = [];
    index = index + 1;

    //I Need a gradient!
    gradients[index].forEach(function(element, key) {
        result[key] = [key, element[0]];
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

By the way, array index starts from 0. So I expect if index==1, it will return:

```
[0, 'rgba(73,115,214,.07)'],
[1, 'rgba(41,189,102,.12)']
```